# What AWS service to use for a nodeJs raw tcp socket chat server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, tcp

I am developing a turn based online mobile board game and I used Heroku before for my socketIo nodeJs server. Now I have shifted to raw Tcp sockets because I don't want the overhead and I want to be more in control. The problem now, per Heroku Support, "You cannot open an arbitrary TCP connection directly to Dyno and send data."

Question: I just signed up for AWS and since there is a whole bunch of services AWS offers, what would be the best solution for my nodeJs Tcp server? I am thinking of EC2 or serverless webapp. If you have thoughts please include pros and cons. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just curious: are you intending to use a browser to connect to your server?

Comment: I found no escape from EC2, because you need to `keep alive`. If it comforts you, you can wrap it in a docker and deploy it to ECS. Once I thought everyone to use the GeenHouse or something like that as far as I recall, it's their IoT warehouse, but it'd have come out pretty expensive...

Comment: Even if you want Redis' magical Pub/Sub, you need a bridge server :(

Comment: @robertklep , no. I'm focusing on android/ios.

Comment: @Lep What was the solution?

Comment: @Tineo, I ended up using EC2. I have more control using that